# PPAPI plugin doesn't load in metro mode Chrome in windows 8

Tags: plugins, google-nativeclient, ppapi

I developed a chrome PPAPI plugin. The plugin works fine in Chrome on windows XP, windows 7. It also works in desktop mode Chrome in windows 8. However, it doesn't load in metro mode Chrome as a plugin. When I type "chrome://plugins/", it didn't show in the plugins list. I'm wondering what's wrong and what it takes to load it as metro mode Chrome plugin. Can anyone help?

I used the following command to launch chrome and register the plugin

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-sandbox  --register-pepper-plugins="C:\ChromePlugin.dll";application/x-nacl localhost:5103/index.html

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Metro mode and how it differs from desktop mode. Are any plugins allowed? Are any shown in chrome://plugins? Also, what does chrome://extensions show? When I develop NaCl stuff, it's as a Chrome extension, so it shows up in that page.

Comment: The only plugins I saw are from google and one from adobe adobe flash player. Does your NaCI stuff show on metro mode chrome

Comment: I don't have Windows 8 to test on immediately. You can go to my site at http://gamemusic.multimedia.cx/ and click in order to install my NaCl extension (hosted in the Chrome Web Store). See where (and if) it shows up (it's called Salty Game Music Player).